# R byte vector to iee 754 float

Tags: r, ieee-754

In R, how do I convert a byte vector to IEEE-754 float (e.g. [0, 108, 4, 71] to 33900.0)?

In Ruby, I would do

```
[1191472128].pack("L").unpack("f") ==> 33900.0
```

I have tried the pack library: `unpack("f", pack("V", 1191472128))`, but it returns 32795.06.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With using the package `mcga` you can convert double types to byte vectors and vice versa:

```
> DoubleToBytes(33900.0)
[1]   0   0   0   0 128 141 224  64
```

and

```
> BytesToDouble(c(0,0,0,0,128,141,224,64))
[1] 33900
```

are the examples.

Answer (score 3):

`readBin` is the answer:

```
library(pack)
v <- pack("V", 1191472128)
readBin(v, size=4, what="double")
# [1] 33900
```

Comment: But I am still wondering how to avoid pack. That would mean one library use less.